# How can I run JavaScript code when JavaScript has been disabled in the browser?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way that JavaScript can be run even when JavaScript has been disabled in the browser by the user?

If not, what fallbacks are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. There is no way to run JavaScript if it has been disabled in the browser. You cannot turn it back on programmatically.

As a fallback, you can always use the `<noscript>` tags to tell the user to turn on JavaScript. For example:

```
<noscript>
    You can browse this site without having JavaScript enabled,
    but to experience the full benefits of the site, please enable JavaScript.
</noscript>
```